# FileMaker database design with calculated fields and filtering

Tags: filemaker

I am trying out Filemaker Pro 12 right now with no previous FM experience, although other basic DB experience.  The issue I have is trying to do filtered queries for a report that span one-to-many relationships.  Here is an example;

The 2 tables:

```
Sample_Replicate
    PK
    Sample FK
    other fields

Weights
    Sample_Replicate_FK (linked to PK of Sample_Replicate)
    Weight
    Measurement type (tare, gross, dry, ash)
    Wash type (null or from list of lab assays)
```

I want to create a report that displays: (gross-tare), (dry-tare)/(gross-tare), (ash-tare)/(gross-tare), and  (dry-tare)/(gross-tare) for all dry weights with non null wash types.

It seems that FM wants me to create columns for each of these values (which is doable as the list of lab assays changes minimally and updating the database would be acceptable, though not preferred).  I have tried to add a gross wt, tare wt, etc to the Sample_Replicate table, but it only is returning the first record (tare wt) when I use calculated field and method:

```
tare wt field = Case ( Weights::Measurement type = "Tare"; Weights::Weights )
gross wt field = Case ( Weights::Measurement type = "Gross"; Weights::Weights )
etc...
```

It also seems to be failing when I add the criteria:

```
 and Is Empty(Weights::Wash type )
```

Could someone point me in the right direction on this issue.  Thanks

**EDIT:**
I came across this: http://www.filemakertoday.com/com/showthread.php/14084-Calculation-based-on-1-to-many-relationship

It seems that I can create ~15 calculated fields for each combination of measurement and wash type on the weights table, then do a sum of these columns in the sample_replicate after adding these 15 columns to the table.  This seems absolutely asinine.  Isn't there a better way to filter results of a one-to-many relationship in FM?

Answer (score 1):

What about the following structure:

```
Replicate
  ID
Wash Weight
  Replicate ID
  Type (null or from list of lab assays)
  Tare
  Gross
  Dry
  Ash
  + calculated fields
```

I assume you only calculate weight ratios of the same wash type. The weight types (tare, gross, etc.) are not just labels here; since you use them in formulas in specific places, they are more like roles, so I think they deserve their own fields.

Answer (score 0):

add tare wt field, etc. in the Weights table but then add a calc field in your Sample_Replicate table to get the sum of all related values

ex: add field "total tare wt" to be "sum ( Weights::tare wt)"

Comment: that was the suggestion from the edit I had added.  I did this an thereby added 15 calculated columns.  There must be a better method out there.

Comment: Instead of the calcs you could setup a script and use ExecuteSQL to grab the values from the weights table. you'd still have to have the fields in the sample_replicate table to hold the query result but that gets you away from having the calc fields in the weights table.

Check out ExecuteSQL in FileMaker Pro 12 Help